# PySpark count values by condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame, a snippet here:

```
[['u1', 1], ['u2', 0]]
```

basically a string field named `f` and either a 1 or a 0 for second element (`is_fav`).

What I need to do is grouping on the first field and counting the occurrences of 1s and 0s. I was hoping to do something like

```
num_fav = count((col("is_fav") == 1)).alias("num_fav")

num_nonfav = count((col("is_fav") == 0)).alias("num_nonfav")

df.groupBy("f").agg(num_fav, num_nonfav)
```

It does not work properly, I get in both cases the same result which amounts to the count for the items in the group, so the filter (whether it is a 1 or a 0) seems to be ignored. Does this depend on how `count` works?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no filter here. Both `col("is_fav") == 1` and `col("is_fav") == 0)` are just boolean expressions and `count` doesn't really care about their value as long as it is defined.

There are many ways you can solve this for example by using simple `sum`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, abs

gpd = df.groupBy("f")
gpd.agg(
    sum("is_fav").alias("fv"),
    (count("is_fav") - sum("is_fav")).alias("nfv")
)
```

or making ignored values undefined (a.k.a [`NULL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29)):

```
exprs = [
    count(when(col("is_fav") == x, True)).alias(c)
    for (x, c) in [(1, "fv"), (0, "nfv")]
]
gpd.agg(*exprs)
```

Comment: I get a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' on the first solution, in sum. I'm sure the column 'is_fav' contains an IntegerType so I don't understand?

Comment: Missing imports or some conflicts with `sum` function? I mean you use built-in `sum` not `functions.sum`.

Comment: Yes that was it, missing import. I guess it was confusing with the built-in Python "sum".